# How do I associate a Storyboard UIViewController with my custom UIViewController class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm running Xcode 7 beta 5 and I have a storyboard with a tab bar controller featuring 4 items.  Each item is a UIViewController.  I created a custom class that is a subclass of UIViewController.

When I go to the storyboard, click on one of the UIViewControllers, go to the Identity Inspector, click on custom class, and try to name my custom class it says,

```
"Launch screens may not set custom classnames"
```

Am I doing something wrong?  I thought this was the way to associate a storyboard's UIViewController with your custom view controller.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a custom class to launch screen. Launch screens main function is to display a view until application loads (not to implement application logic). You should create a new view controller representing object in storyboard (this one should be displayed after application load) and assign a custom class to it.

Comment: Do I create a new storyboard?

Comment: The best practice is to separate launch screen in xib file. You should create a LaunchScreen.xib and set it in application settings -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images (Launch Screen File: LaunchScreen.xib). Whole application views logic should be implemented in a storyboard, which should be also provided in application settings -> General -> Deployment info (Main interface: Main.storyboard). In this way you will not be confused by launch screens and views.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't name your main storyboard `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. Storyboard is not made to implement one view. It is made to implement whole views and interactions logic. You should better name it `Main.storyboard`. Launch screen is a single view. To represent a single view there are `.xib` files. For launch screen it is good idea to name it `LaunchScreen.xib`

Comment: Ok.  For some reason they gave me a storyboard for the launch screen by default.  I get it now.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, custom classes are now forbidden in Launch Screens in Xcode 7. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881645/xcode-7-launch-screens-may-not-set-custom-classnames) as well

Comment: I was able to create a new storyboard, add a VC to it, set a custom class to it, then specify that as launch storyboard. However it seems to ignore the orientation setting I specified. But subclassing that way might just actually work. Tried using Xcode 9, iOS 11.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to customize your Splash Screen then you can create your first view controller as Splash Screen and then set a custom class there.

To tell the system that not to load launch screen just change the settings as mentioned below...

General Tab --> Launch Screen File --> Select "Main" (Basically it's Main Storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom class to any storyboard component except the launchscreen.xib file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I deleted LaunchScreen.storyboard and in main.storyboard I added the custom class which did not give any error later. Hope it helps someone else too.