# Increase font size of launch screen label according to diffrent devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have created a Launch screen.I have added one image & label on it.Now for diffrent screen size devices i am able to increase the size of image with autolayout.But i am not able to increase the font size of label.I can't use custom class of label for storyboard.So is there any way with i am able to increase font size for multiple devices on launch screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically changing font size of UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865458/dynamically-changing-font-size-of-uilabel)

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080247/nslabel-autoshrink-with-top-constraints/40082296#40082296 i hope it's work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Option for different `font size` for different `size class` is available in `storyboard`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NO. It is not possible to implement `custom font` for `LaunchScreen`, since `LaunchScreen` will be loaded before your custom fonts load. Better create different images with the text you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not possible you can write code for a `launchScreen` and handle some logic as for a conventional `ViewController`. Also you cannot use a custom class of label or extension. You can use only Auto-Layout and size classes. The detailed explanation is in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881645/xcode-7-launch-screens-may-not-set-custom-classnames)